# How to add lemmatization and tokenization to scattertext

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I am using scattertext to parse a document in xlsx, but I am using non-English language and I will be most happy to add lemmatization and tokenization. I've checked these on spaCy alone and it works, but I have no clue how to integrate it in my scattertext plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
import pl_core_news_sm
nlp = spacy.load("pl_core_news_sm")


#nlp = pl_core_news_sm.load()

import scattertext as st
from pprint import pprint
from spacy.lang.pl.stop_words import STOP_WORDS


df = pd.read_excel("/home/poodle/Desktop/myfile.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Arkusz1', error_bad_lines = False)

corpus = st.CorpusFromPandas(
    df,
    category_col = 'Evaluation',
    text_col = 'Opis',
    nlp = st.whitespace_nlp_with_sentences).build().remove_terms(STOP_WORDS, ignore_absences=True)
    
html = st.produce_scattertext_explorer(corpus,
    category = 'Nonsense',
    category_name = 'Nonsense',
    not_category_name = 'Correct',
    minimum_term_frequency = 0,
    width_in_pixels = 800,
    metadata = corpus.get_df()['Autor'],
    save_svg_button = True)

open('./Convention-Visualization6.html', 'wb').write(html.encode('utf-8'))
```

---

Is my code overall ok?

Answer (score 2):

Scattertext has a specific pipeline for displaying lemmas instead of tokens.

To start, please use spaCy to parse your data frame of documents instead of scattertext's whitespace tokenizer.

I'm using spaCy's English parser here, but you should be sure to use a Polish version, if available.

```
import scattertext as st
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

df = st.SampleCorpora.ConventionData2012.get_data().assign(
    parse=lambda df: df.text.apply(nlp)
)
```

Next, I create a Scattertext corpus from the data frame, using the column containing the spaCy Doc objects we created int he previous step.

Also, we use the `st.FeatsFromSpacyDoc(use_lemmas=True)` feature extractor to extract lemmas instead of tokens.

```
corpus = st.CorpusFromParsedDocuments(
    df, category_col='party', parsed_col='parse',
    feats_from_spacy_doc=st.FeatsFromSpacyDoc(use_lemmas=True)
)
```

I like use only unigrams (unilemmas in this case) and isolate the 2,000 most informative lemmas to display.

```
corpus = corpus.build().get_unigram_corpus().compact(st.AssociationCompactor(2000))
```

Finally, I create an html object which makes each axis in the plot the dense rank of a lemma's frequency.

```
html = st.produce_scattertext_explorer(
    corpus,
    category='democrat',
    category_name='Democratic',
    not_category_name='Republican',
    minimum_term_frequency=0, pmi_threshold_coefficient=0,
    width_in_pixels=1000, metadata=corpus.get_df()['speaker'],
    transform=st.Scalers.dense_rank,
    max_overlapping=3
)
open('./demo_lemmas.html', 'w').write(html)
print('open ./demo_lemmas.html in Chrome')
```

Comment: It all works but one thing. Instead of df = st.SampleCorpora.ConventionData2012.get_data().assign(
    parse=lambda df: df.text.apply(nlp)), I am loading my data from excel file. df = pd.read_excel("/home/poodle/Desktop/wykop_sc26,06.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Arkusz1', error_bad_lines = False).

Then it raises a get.data and text issues because of a dataframe. What should I do?